# how to use html tags in prestashop's smarty translations?

Tags: templates, smarty, translation, prestashop, smarty3

I can't find a solution. What I've got to do is translate this:

```
se stai inserendo un indirizzo per consegna all'interno dell'area <span class=orange>EXPO</span>
```

into this:

```
If your delivery address is in the <span class=orange>EXPO</span> area
```

If I use tags, like this:

```
{l s="se stai inserendo un indirizzo per consegna all'interno dell'area <span class=orange>EXPO</span>"}
```

They won't be seen. So what?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Prestashop provides an undocumented solution for this:

You can add a `tags` parameter inside the `{l}` function call. The value of this parameter is an array of string. To add a tag from this array in the string you need to use `[i]x[/i]` (where `i` is the tag index in the array starting from 1 and `x` is the text you want to see surrounded by the tag)

For example if I want to render this string in a single translation line:

```html
<strong>Welcome</strong> <i class="name_class">Florian Lemaitre</i>!
```

I can use this code:

```html
{l s='[1]Welcome[/1] [2]%s[/2]!' sprintf=[$name] tags=['<strong>', '<i class="name_class">']}
```

In your case you can use:

```html
{l s="se stai inserendo un indirizzo per consegna all'interno dell'area [1]EXPO[/1]" tags=['<span class=orange>']}
```

---

You can find the related code in file `classes/Translate.php` :

```php
/**
* Perform operations on translations after everything is escaped and before displaying it
*/
public static function postProcessTranslation($string, $params)
{
    // If tags were explicitely provided, we want to use them *after* the translation string is escaped.
    if (!empty($params['tags'])) {
        foreach ($params['tags'] as $index => $tag) {
            // Make positions start at 1 so that it behaves similar to the %1$d etc. sprintf positional params
            $position = $index + 1;
            // extract tag name
            $match = array();
            if (preg_match('/^\s*<\s*(\w+)/', $tag, $match)) {
                $opener = $tag;
                $closer = '</'.$match[1].'>';

                $string = str_replace('['.$position.']', $opener, $string);
                $string = str_replace('[/'.$position.']', $closer, $string);
                $string = str_replace('['.$position.'/]', $opener.$closer, $string);
            }
        }
    }

    return $string;
}
```

Comment: This is 2023 and it's still not documented, but still working on Prestashop v8

Answer (score 2):

The translation function will remove all html tags so you will have to use an alternative like so

```
{capture "string"}
  {l s="se stai inserendo un indirizzo per consegna all'interno dell'area _h1_EXPO_h2_"}
{/capture}
{$smarty.capture.string|replace:'_h1_':'<span class="orange">'|replace:'_h2_':'</span>'}
```

`_h1_` and `_h2_` are in the translation and they are replaced by `<span class="orange">` and `</span>` respectively

The smarty [capture](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.capture.tpl) function is used to get the translation into the variable `string` instead of dispaying it

So your English translation would be something like this
`If your delivery address is in the _h1_EXPO_h2_ area`

Comment: I'll take a deeper look, we can even make a pull request and see how it goes (target: PrestaShop 1.7)

Answer (score 0):

Try to keep HTML out of your translation strings. You can do that by making two strings:

```
{l s="se stai inserendo un indirizzo per consegna all'interno dell'area"} <span class="orange">{l s='EXPO'}</span>
```

Comment: No in this case I can't. My example is quite clear: I need to move words in translation ('EXPO' before and after the 'area' word), that's why.

Answer (score 0):

```
{assign var="name" value="Bob"}
{l s='[1]Welcome[/1] [2] %s [/2]!' sprintf=[$name] tags=['<strong>', '<i class="name_class">']}
```

give us

```
[1]Welcome[/1] [2] Bob [/2]!
```